# How to rewrite a tensor as a matrix

Tags: matrix, tensors

I put
`{TensorProduct[{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]}/Sqrt[2]//MatrixForm`
and I got
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
as a result.
I now would like to rewrite this as
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
to calculate eigenvalues of this matrix above.

Could you tell me how?

Answer (score 10):

```
mat = {TensorProduct[{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]/Sqrt[2]};

FixedPoint[ArrayFlatten, mat] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 8):

```
mat = {TensorProduct[{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]/ Sqrt[2]};

ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten /@ mat] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thanks for catching..

Answer (score 7):

```
X = {TensorProduct[{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]/Sqrt[2]};

Flatten[X, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}]

(*    {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0, 0}}    *)
```

Comment: Side note: to understand this syntax of `Flatten`, one may read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14810/1871).

Answer (score 5):

Another option

```
(m = {TensorProduct[{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]}/Sqrt[2]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
m1 = ArrayFlatten[m[[1, 1]], 2]
m2 = ArrayFlatten[m[[1, 2]], 2]
Join[m1, m2, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]