# Get a list with alternate values of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

If I have two lists such as:

`list1={60,65,70,75,80,85,87}`

`list2= {4.14166, 4.15138, 3.22417, 2.9524, -0.188672, 0.0653777, -0.63967}`

How can I combine the two list to get a list like

`list3={{value1list1,value1list2},{value2list1,value2list2},{value3list1,value3list2}....etc}`

or with numbers

`list3={{60,4.14166},{70, 4.15138},{75,3.22417}....etc}`

Comment: `Transpose[{list1, list2}]`

Comment: `Thread[{list1,list2}]`

Comment: thank you both. they work great !

Comment: `Flatten[{list1,list2},{{2}}]` probably also deserves a mention, a possible advantage being that it works with 'ragged' lists. (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of more ways, in addition to the methods mentioned in the comments:

**1. Using MapThread**

```
   In[115]:= MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {list1, list2}]

   Out[115]= {{60, 4.14166}, {65, 4.15138}, {70, 3.22417}, {75, 2.9524}, {80, -0.188672}, {85, 0.0653777}, {87, -0.63967}}
```

**2. Using Map and Lenght of the list**

```
   In[116]:= {list1[[#]], list2[[#]]} & /@ Range[Length[list1]]

   Out[116]= {{60, 4.14166}, {65, 4.15138}, {70, 3.22417}, {75, 2.9524}, {80, -0.188672}, {85, 0.0653777}, {87, -0.63967}}
```