# What is the best way to flatten a nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list called `matcoeffE` which has dimensions `{10, 9, 7, 2}`. However, I want to build a matrix with dimensions `{180,7}` and then export it as an Excel file. At the first step I used:

```
newmat = FlattenAt[matcoeffE, Transpose[{Range[10]}]];
```

so dimensions of `newmat` became `{90, 7, 2}`. After that I have to flatten 2 (2*90) and get a new matrix which has dimensions `{180,7}` which produces an Excel file with 190 rows and 7 columns (in a single sheet). My mean is: `newmat` has 90 rows and 7 columns which each column has two numbers in it. I want to second number of each this two-member list goes to the next row (namely each second member is placed under the first member), so that the dimensions will be `{180,7}`. I tried to show my mean schematically as follows:

[image]

I tried `Splice` for example, but it didn't work. In fact I always have a problem with flattening the nested list. How can I solve my problem? Is there a simple and general way to flatten nested lists?

Comment: To do the first part, you could use `newmat = ArrayReshape[matcoeffE, {90, 7, 2}];`  but I do not understand the rest of your question now.

Comment: @Nasser See my updates

Comment: What do you mean by *"my mean"*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code is the best illustration

```
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 9, 7, 2}];
Dimensions[a]
(*{10, 9, 7, 2}*)

b = Transpose[a, {1, 2, 4, 3}];
Dimensions[b]
(*{10, 9, 2, 7}*)

c1 = Flatten[b, 1];
Dimensions[c1]
(*{90, 2, 7}*)

c2 = Flatten[b, 2];
Dimensions[c2]
(*{180, 7}*)
```

One can do everything at once

```
c3 = Flatten[a, {{1, 2, 4}, {3}}];
Dimensions[c3]
(*{180, 7}*)
```

And verify

```
Norm[c3 - c2]
(* 0 *)
```

### Explanations

There are some differences between `Transpose` and `Flatten` that one needs to take care of.

- If you write `b = Transpose[a, {1, 2, 4, 3}]` it means that the 3rd dimension of `a` will become the 4th dimension of `b`. That is, `{1, 2, 4, 3}` denotes the *destination* of dimensions.
- Let the second argument of `Flatten` be `n`. `n+1` tells you how many dimensions starting from the first one will be combined together. This means `Flatten[b, 2]` combines 3 first dimensions into one.
- `Flatten` with a 2nd argument being a list is slightly different:
  `Flatten[a, {{1, 2, 4}, {3}}]` means combine dimensions 1, 2 and 4 into the first dimension, combine dimension 3 into the second dimension. And so on. As you can see this is very flexible as it allows to transpose and flatten at the same time.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, can you add some explanations to your answer? I really need to understand the way `Flatten` works, for example how you build `c3` in one step?

Comment: @Wisdom Yes, see the edits

Comment: Good job and great trick! However I need to practice it to understand deeply. Thanks again.

Comment: @Wisdom see also [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/142)