# How can I apply a function only to even-index elements of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

`A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
and, `Dd[P_] := P + 1`

How can I map "Dd" into "A" such that the outcome is: {1, 3, 3, 5, 5}?

(Dd is only applied to the elements that its indexes are even)

Comment: Welcome to the community. `D` is a built-in Mathematica function. It's recommended to not use single letter with upper case function names. Try `MapAt[# + 1 &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2 ;; ;; 2]`

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 12):

I changed `D` to `Dd`:

```
MapAt[Dd, A, 2 ;; ;; 2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But just to see if I got all of it, the "2 ;; ;; 2" thing translates exacly to: "All even indexes"?

Comment: @MatheusMantovaniMeneghel lookup Span in docs.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the new [`ApplyTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html):

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Dd[P_] := P + 1

A[[2 ;; ;; 2]] //= Dd;
A
(*    {1, 3, 3, 5, 5}    *)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
alist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

---

Using `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexed[If[EvenQ @@ #2, #1 + 1, #] &, alist]
```

---

Using addition:

Generate  {0,1,0,1..} array

```
blist = (Flatten@ConstantArray[{0, 1}, Ceiling[Length@alist/2]])[[1 ;;
     Length@alist]]
```

> {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}

```
alist + blist
```

---

Using `ReplacePart`:

```
evenrange = Range[2, Length@alist, 2];

ReplacePart[alist, Thread[evenrange -> alist[[evenrange]] + 1]]
```

---

Result:

> ```
> {1, 3, 3, 5, 5}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

```
SubsetMap[dd, arr, 2 ;; -1 ;; 2]

(* {1, 3, 3, 5, 5} *)
```

where:

```
arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
dd[p_] := p + 1
```

**Just for fun**

```
{arr[[1;;-1;;2]], dd@arr[[2;;-1;;2]]} // Flatten[#, {{2,1}}]&

(* {1, 3, 3, 5, 5} *) 

MapIndexed[#1+Boole@EvenQ[#2][[1]]&, arr]

(* {1, 3, 3, 5, 5} *)
```

Comment: To transpose a 'ragged' array with `Flatten`, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106) by [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)

Answer (score 7):

Using `Position` and `Map`:

```
Map[If[EvenQ[Det[Position[A, #]]] === True, # + 1, #] &, A]
(*{1, 3, 3, 5, 5}*)
```

Using `Outer`, `Range` and `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[# + 1 &, A, Outer[List, Range[2, Length[A], 2]]]
(*{1, 3, 3, 5, 5}*)
```

Using `Position` and `Map`:

```
Plus[Map[If[EvenQ[Det[Position[A, #]]] === True, 1, 0] &, A], A]
(*{1, 3, 3, 5, 5}*)
```

Comment: A very nice use of `Det`, too

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> x + 1, 2 ;; ;; 2] @ list
```

> {1, 3, 3, 5, 5}