# How to untensor a tensor?

Tags: matrix, tensors

What should I do to convert a matrix of matrices to a non-nested matrix?

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_1} & {b_1} \\
 {c_1} & {d_1} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_2} & {b_2} \\
 {c_2} & {d_2} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_3} & {b_3} \\
 {c_3} & {d_3} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_4} & {b_4} \\
 {c_4} & {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 {a_1} & {b_1} & {a_2} & {b_2} \\
 {c_1} & {d_1} & {c_2} & {d_2} \\
 {a_3} & {b_3} & {a_4} & {b_4} \\
 {c_3} & {d_3} & {c_4} & {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

Comment: We got an excellent answer pointer, this would be a good opportunity for new members looking to gain some reputation to write up an answer with some nice examples.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the comment, this is exactly what `ArrayFlatten` is designed to do. Straight from the documentation:

> ArrayFlatten[{{$m_{11}$,$m_{12}$,...},{$m_{21}$,$m_{22}$,...},...}]
> creates a single flattened matrix from a matrix of matrices $m_{ij}$

So for your example,

```
sub[i_] = Partition[Table[Alphabet[][[j]][i], {j, 4}], 2];
m = Partition[Table[sub[i], {i, 4}], 2];
flat = ArrayFlatten[m];
MatrixForm /@ {m, flat}
```

[image]