# Matricization of a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector, tuples

**Definitions**

Define a vector  `Tuples[a[0, 1], n]` of elements $a[i_1,...,i_n], i_j \in \{0,1\} ~\forall j$, that is for instance

`{a[0, 0, 0, 0], a[0, 0, 0, 1], a[0, 0, 1, 0], a[0, 0, 1, 1],  a[0, 1, 0, 0], a[0, 1, 0, 1], a[0, 1, 1, 0], a[0, 1, 1, 1],  a[1, 0, 0, 0], a[1, 0, 0, 1], a[1, 0, 1, 0], a[1, 0, 1, 1],  a[1, 1, 0, 0], a[1, 1, 0, 1], a[1, 1, 1, 0], a[1, 1, 1, 1]}`

with n=4,

Define a set of tuples $I_{l_k}\in \mathbb{R}^l$ with $l\in \{1,...,n-1\}$ and $k\in \{1,...,\binom{l}{n}\}$. For instance with n=2, there is one possible value for $l$, that is $l=1$. Therefore, there exist 2 different tuple $I_{1_1}=\{1\}$ and $I_{1_2}=\{2\}$. For n=3, there is two possible value for $l$, that is $l=1$ and $l=2$. Therefore, for $l=1$ there exists 3 different tuple $I_{1_1}=\{1\}$, $I_{1_2}=\{2\}$ and $I_{1_3}=\{3\}$. For $l=2$, there exists 3 different tuple $I_{2_1}=\{1,2\}$, $I_{2_2}=\{1,3\}$ and $I_{3_3}=\{2,3\}$.

**Goal**

I would like to generate a matrix $M_{I_{l_k}}$ whose elements are the elements of the vector `Tuples[a[0, 1], n]`, with respect to a given tuple $I_{l_k}$ in the following way :
The rows are the elements of `Tuples[a[0, 1], n]` whose indices $i_j$ whose location $j$ is specified by the elements of the tuple $I_{l_k}$ are constant while the other indices vary from 0 to 1 in a binary order. The column are the elements of `Tuples[a[0, 1], n]` whose indices $i_j$ whose location $j$ is *not* specified by the elements of the tuple $I_{l_k}$ are constant while the other indices vary from 0 to 1 in a binary order.

**Example**

Here is the example for n=3. Since I can't write it in LaTeX here for some unknown reasons, this is a printscreen from a document.

[image]

Comment: I don't follow the generation of `I`, and I think it's because I don't understand `k`. Is `k` a member of the set `Range[Binominal[n-1,n]]`?

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability $k$ simply refer to the number of distinct ways one can choose $l$ elements of {1,...,n}. For a given $l$, there exist Binominal[n,l] possible ways to make this choice. Each one of this choice is represented by a tuple $I_{l_k}$ whose elements are the natural numbers chosen in {1,...,n}. Is it clearer ? If it suits you better, consider that k is an index that labels the different ways $I_l$ of choosing $l$ elements of {1,...,n}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this works:

```
mats[lLen_, nMax_] /; lLen < nMax := Module[
   {
    indices = Subsets[Range[1, nMax], {lLen}],
    as = Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, Tuples[a[0, 1], nMax], nMax - 1]
   },
   Table[
     Flatten[as, {ind, Complement[Range[1, nMax], ind]}],
     {ind, indices}
    ]
  ]
```

Here is an explanation of the code.

1. The code snippet `indices = Subsets[Range[1, nMax], {lLen}]` generates the list of $I_{l_k}$'s, since $I_l$ really is just the list of subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ that have size $l$.
2. The code snippet `as = Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, Tuples[a[0, 1], nMax], nMax - 1]` is the fastest (and just about most succinct) way I could come up with of generating the collection of `a[ ... ]`'s but nested in a way that would allow me to use an element of `indices`, i.e., one of the $I_{l_k}$'s, to automatically `Flatten` `as` in the correct way. Alternatively, `as = ArrayReshape[Tuples[a[0, 1], nMax], ConstantArray[2, nMax]]` works as well, and is perhaps easier to parse, but they seems equivalent in terms of speed. This basically forms an $n$-component tensor $a_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}$ with $i_j=0$ or 1 and $a_{i_1,i_2,\dots, i_n}=$`a[i_1,i_2,...,i_n]`. In other words,

   ```
   as[[i_1+1, i_2+1, ..., i_n+1]] = a[i_1,i_2,...,i_n]
   ```

   so that the $j$'th index $i_n$ correspond to the `j`th level in the list `as`.
3. Finally, the heart of the code, which is `Flatten[as, {ind, Complement[Range[1, nMax], ind]}]`. I knew that `Flatten` should work, because it allows us to combine particular levels of a nested list in a controlled way. In addition, I knew that `Tuples` would generate the indices of `a` in the correct binary order, and that `Partition`ing the set should respect that order. After that, it was simply a matter of experimenting/guessing to see what works.

   Here is how it works: From the documentation,

   > `Flatten[list,{{s11,s12,...},{s21,s22,...},...}]`
   > flattens list by combining all levels `sij` to make each level `i` in the result.

   Since the `i`th index of `a` is at the `i`th level of `as`, we just need to `Flatten` those levels that appear in `I_{l_k}` together (because the order of 0's and 1's will automatically be respected) and then `Flatten` the *rest* of the levels together (because again the order of 0's and 1's will automatically be respected).

   So, `ind` in the `Table` is an iterator that picks out one element of `indices`, which is one of the $I_{l_k}$'s, and `Complement[Range[1, nMax], ind]}]` collects the *rest* of the indices. One way to think about the third argument of `Flatten` is that it chooses an order for the iterators first, and then chooses which levels to `Flatten` together.  The order of the iterators is given by `Join[ind, Complement[Range[1, nMax], ind]]`, which for $I_{2_2}$ for $n=3$ would be `Join[{1, 3}, {2}] == {1, 3, 2}`. After it's chosen this iteration order, it will then `Flatten` levels 1 and 3 to be level 1 in the list.

It's best to see an example. For $n=3$, `as` is

```
Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, Tuples[a[0, 1], 3], 3 - 1]
```

[image]

The rows are the first level/index, and we can see that in each row, the values of $i_1$ in `a[i_1,...]` are all the same in each row. The columns are the second level/index, and we can see that in each column, all the $i_2$'s in `a[i_1,i_2,i_3]` are the same. Finally, the two-element lists in each matrix entry compose the third level/index, and we can see that the first element of each of these lists is `a[i_1,i_2,0]`, whereas the second element of each list is `a[i_1,i_2,1]`, indicating that the $i_3$'s are the same at the same spots in level 3.

Let's consider $I_{2_2}=\{1,3\}$. Then, taking `ind` to be `{1, 3}` and `Complement[Range[1, 3], ind]}]` to be `{2}`, we can see that `Flatten` iterates over indices 1 and 3 first, then over 2. That is to say, it chooses values of 1 and 3 first, then iterates over 2 to make the first row. For the first row, then, we fix the values of $i_1$ and $i_3$ to be 0, and iterate over $i_2$, leaving `a[0, 0, 0]` and `a[0, 1, 0]`. Thus, we see that the first and third indices of `a` are fixed in this row, with the second index iterated over in binary order (because binary order was automatically respected by `Tuples` and `Partition`ing), leaving the first row of $M_{I_{2_2}}$, which is

[image]

Comment: @Baloo This works on your test cases, and the you can test to see if it works more generally.  If so, I can try to find the time to explain what's going on. The trick is that [`Flatten` does amazing things](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument).

Comment: Well, I don't know if you get those notifications, but I wrote 2 comments and deleted them because at first glance I didn't see how perfectly it fulfilled my expectations. Thanks a lot for your time, this is exactly what I looked for ! I would indeed be very interested to understand the tools and logic you used to write this :) Thanks again !

Comment: @Baloo I've added an explanation. It might or might not make sense, but I've added what I think is the necessary explanation of what `Flatten` is doing, because that's the heart of the thing, combined with the proper partitioning of the original vector `a`.

Comment: Your explanation is really good, I learned a lot just by reading it. Thanks a lot for your time, you're awesome !