# How to Partition List into sublists so that it orders down columns when placed into a Grid instead of across rows

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, sorting, grid-layouts

Partitioning a `List` into sub-lists and placing them directly into a Grid orders sub-lists across rows. Is there an idiot-proof built-in function or a simple algorithm for ordering sub-lists down columns for an unknown number of `list` elements with an unknown end-user selected `n` of sub-list lengths?

This outputs ordered across rows:

```
list = Range[8]
n = 3
Grid[Partition[list, UpTo[n]]]
```

Out:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8
```

The goal is ordered down columns:

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response using a built-in function is that of Syed, no doubt. However, it is possible to build a list with the required permutations:

```
permutation =  Flatten[ Table[Range[i, Length[list], n], 
                       {i, 1, Ceiling[Length[list]/n]}] ];
Grid[Partition[Permute[list, permutation], UpTo[n]]]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Grid@Flatten[Partition[list, UpTo[n]], {{2}, {1}}]
```

$$\begin{array}{ccc}  1 & 4 & 7 \\  2 & 5 & 8 \\  3 & 6 & \text{} \\ \end{array}$$

Please see the docs for [Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) and browse for `ragged` under `Applications`.

---

OR

The `Transpose` operation requires a rectangular array, so one can use `PadRight` prior to it with the same result. Choose `"x"` to be something unikely to be found in the data.

```
Transpose@(PadRight[#, n, "x"] & /@ Partition[list, UpTo[n]]) /. 
  "x" -> Nothing // Grid
```

Comment: Nice I did know `UpTo` can be used like that. For the `Partition[list, UpTo[n]]` there is also a resource function [NearEqualPartition](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NearEqualPartition/). For OP: For using `Flatten` like a transposition for ragged lists see particularly the answer by WReach here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119/flatten-command-matrix-as-second-argument

Comment: @Syed thank you. the second part works beautifully. :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to partition a given list of length: m into sublists of length: n and arrange the sublists as column in a grid. This can be done by choosing every n-th element with an offset from 0..m/n:

```
  getGrid[list_, n_] := Module[{m = Length[list]},
  Grid[Table[
    If[(t = j + n i) >= m, Nothing, t + 1], {j, 0, n - 1}, {i, 0, m/n}]]
  ]
```

We may test this by:

```
list = Range[8];
getGrid[list, 2]
```

[image]

`getGrid[list, 3`]

[image]

```
getGrid[list, 4]
```

[image]

Comment: How could be this modified so that it partitions (order down columns) based on number of columns desired? For example `getGrid[list_, columns_]:=...`

Comment: Use: `getGrid[list, Ceiling[Length[list]/columns]]`