# Joining two lists with Transpose and with an offset

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of the same length `n`.

For the case of `n=5`, these would be:

```
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};
```

I want to `Transpose` these lists but with an offset of `1` creating a resulting list with one additional element. Such as:

```
wantResult = {{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},...,{b5}}
```

I can sort of do this by prepending `{}` to `a`, and appending `{}` to `b`  resulting in the following two lists:

```
az = Append[a,{}] = {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,{}}
bz = Prepend[b,{}] = {{},b1,b2,b3,b4,b5}
```

Then `Transpose[{az,bz}]`, but I get:

```
{ {a1,{}},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},...,{{},b5} }
```

where the empty braces/lists are the problem :(..

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: `Map[Flatten]@Transpose[{az,bz}]`?

Comment: Thank you! Many great answers below. I am working through them and dread having to pick a single one to mark as answered. This is a great collection of variations and is growing my mind already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{#[[{1}]], ##2, #[[{-1}]]} & @@ Transpose[{a, RotateRight @ b}]
```

> ```
> {{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}
> ```

Also

```
Inner[ List, a, RotateRight @ b, {#[[{1}]], ##2, #[[{-1}]]} &]
```

> ```
> {{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}
> ```

For fun:

```
☺ = {#[[{1}]], ##2, #[[{-1}]]} & @@ ({#, {##2, #} & @@ #2}\[Transpose]) &;

☺[a, b]
```

> ```
> {{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}
> ```

Comment: it was fun! .. thanks for the great answers :)

Comment: I accepted this answer as it profiles fastest. All the answers work, and make a great collection of alternatives to demonstrate the many ways to achieve this task.

Answer (score 6):

**Using `Partition` and `Riffle`:**

If both lists have the same length, then:

```
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};


g[a_List, b_List] := {{First@a}}~Join~
  Partition[Riffle[Rest@a, Most@b], UpTo[2]]~Join~{{Last@b}}

g[a, b]
```

---

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
h[a_List, b_List] := 
 Module[{chunks = {1, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[2, Length@a - 1], 1}},
  Riffle[a, b] // TakeList[#, chunks] & // Map[Reverse]
  ]

h[a, b]
```

---

**Using `Transpose`:**

```
Transpose[{Append[a, x], Prepend[b, x]}] /. x -> Nothing
```

---

*Result(s):*

> {{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_, y_] := Module[{r = Thread[{Most@x, Rest@y}]},
  Join[{{x[[1]]}}, r, {{y[[-1]]}}]]
```

Testing

```
am = Array[a, 10];
bm = Array[b, 10];
f[am, bm]
```

yields: {{a[1]}, {a[1], b[2]}, {a[2], b[3]}, {a[3], b[4]}, {a[4],
b[5]}, {a[5], b[6]}, {a[6], b[7]}, {a[7], b[8]}, {a[8],
b[9]}, {a[9], b[10]}, {b[10]}}

Answer (score 3):

Alternative ways to combine `Partition` and `Riffle`:

```
Partition[Riffle[a, b], 2, 2, {-1, 1}, {}, Reverse @* List]
```

> ```
> {{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}
> ```

```
Partition[Riffle[Append[Last @ b] @ a, b, {3, -2, 2}], 2, 2, {-1, 1}, {}]
```

> ```
> {{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};

MapAt[Nothing, {1, 2}] @ Append[{Last @ b}] @
 Thread[{a, RotateRight @ b}]
```

{{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}

```
Append[{Last @ b}] @ Prepend[{First @ a}] @ 
 Thread[{a[[2 ;;]], b[[;; -2]]}]
```

{{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) to transpose a 'ragged' array (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/106)):

```
Flatten[{Rest@a,b},{{2}}]//Prepend[{First@a}]

(* {{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};
```

Another way using `Insert` and `Thread`:

```
l1 = Thread[{a, b}];
l2 = Thread[{a[[2 ;;]], b[[;; -2]]}];

Insert[List /@ Diagonal@#[[{1, -1}]] &@l1, Splice@l2, 2]

{{a1}, {a2, b1}, {a3, b2}, {a4, b3}, {a5, b4}, {b5}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick profile of all the answers so far. They all work and thank you. I will mark the fastest one as the answer as that's a key goal of mine.

````
a = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5};


f[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{r = Thread[{Most@x, Rest@y}]}, 
   Join[{{x[[1]]}}, r, {{y[[-1]]}}]];
f[a, b];

g[a_List, b_List] := {{First@a}}~Join~
   Partition[Riffle[Rest@a, Most@b], UpTo[2]]~Join~{{Last@b}};
g[a, b];

h[a_List, b_List] := 
  Module[{chunks = {1, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[2, Length@a - 1], 
      1}}, Riffle[a, b] // TakeList[#, chunks] & // Map[Reverse]];
h[a, b];

(*Transpose[{Append[a,x],Prepend[b,x]}]/. x->Nothing*)
i[x_, y_] := 
  Transpose[{Append[x, u], Prepend[y, u]}] /. u -> Nothing;
i[a, b];

(*{#[[{1}]],##2,#[[{-1}]]}&@@Transpose[{a,RotateRight@b}]*)
j[x_, y_] := {#[[{1}]], ##2, #[[{-1}]]} & @@ 
   Transpose[{x, RotateRight@y}];
j[a, b];

(*Inner[List,a,RotateRight@b,{#[[{1}]],##2,#[[{-1}]]}&]*)
k[x_, y_] := 
  Inner[List, x, RotateRight@y, {#[[{1}]], ##2, #[[{-1}]]} &];
k[a, b];

(*\[HappySmiley]={#[[{1}]],##2,#[[{-1}]]}&@@({#,{##2,#}&@@#2}\
\[Transpose])&;*)
\[HappySmiley] = {#[[{1}]], ##2, #[[{-1}]]} & @@ ({#, {##2, #} & @@ \
#2}\[Transpose]) &;
\[HappySmiley][a, b];

(*MapAt[Nothing,{1,2}]@Append[{Last@b}]@Thread[{a,RotateRight@b}]*)
l[x_, y_] := 
  MapAt[Nothing, {1, 2}]@Append[{Last@y}]@Thread[{x, RotateRight@y}];
l[a, b];

(*Append[{Last@b}]@Prepend[{First@a}]@Thread[{a[[2;;]],b[[;;-2]]}]*)
m[x_, y_] := 
  Append[{Last@x}]@
   Prepend[{First@y}]@Thread[{x[[2 ;;]], y[[;; -2]]}];
m[a, b];

(*Partition[Riffle[a,b],2,2,{-1,1},{},Reverse@*List]*)
n[x_, y_] := Partition[Riffle[x, y], 2, 2, {-1, 1}, {}, Reverse@*List];
n[a, b];

(*Partition[Riffle[Append[Last@b]@a,b,{3,-2,2}],2,2,{-1,1},{}]*)
o[x_, y_] := 
  Partition[Riffle[Append[Last@y]@a, y, {3, -2, 2}], 2, 
   2, {-1, 1}, {}];
o[a, b];

Print["f[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[f[a, b], 1]]
Print["g[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[g[a, b], 1]]
Print["h[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[h[a, b], 1]]
Print["i[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[i[a, b], 1]]
Print["j[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[j[a, b], 1]]
Print["k[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[k[a, b], 1]]
Print["\[HappySmiley][a,b]", RepeatedTiming[\[HappySmiley][a, b], 1]]
Print["l[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[l[a, b], 1]]
Print["m[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[m[a, b], 1]]
Print["n[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[n[a, b], 1]]
Print["o[a,b]", RepeatedTiming[o[a, b], 1]]


f[a,b]{4.612*10^-6,{{a1},{a1,b2},{a2,b3},{a3,b4},{a4,b5},{b5}}}

g[a,b]{5.08331*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}

h[a,b]{7.72621*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}

i[a,b]{6.75102*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}

j[a,b]{4.82434*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}

k[a,b]{2.8945*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}

\[HappySmiley][a,b]{4.89292*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b3},{a3,b4},{a4,b5},{a5,b1},{b2}}}

l[a,b]{3.28372*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}

m[a,b]{3.12413*10^-6,{{b1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{a5}}}

n[a,b]{4.9749*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}

o[a,b]{3.91459*10^-6,{{a1},{a2,b1},{a3,b2},{a4,b3},{a5,b4},{b5}}}
```
````